# Varnish logrotate issue

Tags: varnish, logrotate, log-rotation

I have this in `logrotate.d/varnish` file:

```
/var/log/varnish/*log {
                create 640 http log
                compress
                postrotate
                        /bin/kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/varnishncsa.pid 2>/dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
                endscript
        }
```

And this in my `/etc/rc.local` file:

```
varnishncsa -a -w /var/log/varnish/access.log -D -P /var/run/varnishncsa.pid
```

But when logrotate creates a new `access.log` file, it remains blank. I have to do `sh /etc/rc.local` for logs to be saved in that file. As logrotation happens weekly, I have to execute that `rc.local` every week to get the logs saved in `access.log` file. What can be the issue here?

Comment: Did you get `varnishncsa` running after execute `logrotate`? Which distro are you running?

Comment: Yes it will be running after logrotate gets executed. The distro I'm running is ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Could you please run `logrotate` manually and give us output: `logrotate -v -f /etc/logrotate.d/varnish`?

Answer (score 2):

I know absolutely nothing about varnish, but it sure looks like you should be sending it a [SIGHUP](https://www.varnish-cache.org/lists/pipermail/varnish-misc/2007-December/001219.html) to do log rotation, not a SIGUSR1.

A new blank logfile is a pretty good indicator that the daemon isn't getting the message that it's supposed to close it's old logfile and switch to a new one.

Comment: 'SIGHUP' didn't work.

Comment: SIGHUP is pretty much the universal 'tell a daemon to close and reopen logfile' signal.  I'm confused why if sighup didn't work you thought sigusr1 would?  Well, it's certainly possible that varnish uses sigusr1, like I said I'm not knowledgeable about it.  But, I wonder if the problem is still that something is wrong with sighup handling in your version of varnish.

Comment: @nixnotwin: It's kill -HUP, not -SIGHUP

Comment: Tested both, HUP actually kills the process and USR1 does nothing. USR2 also did nothing. So ended up just restarting the process.